# openshift 3 REST API authentication

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Can we authenticate against OpenShift enterprise 3.2 or 3.3 REST API's using username and password instead of tokens?

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in openshift documentation:

Requests to the OpenShift Container Platform API are authenticated using the following methods:

- **OAuth Access Tokens**

Obtained from the OpenShift Container Platform OAuth server using the /oauth/authorize and /oauth/token endpoints.

Sent as an Authorization: Bearer…​ header or an access_token=…​ query parameter

- **X.509 Client Certificates**

Requires a HTTPS connection to the API server.
Verified by the API server against a trusted certificate authority bundle.

So you need to authenticate using either of these ways

Comment: thanks, I have always authenticated using HTTPS only with OAuth Access tokens as I think openshift API's doesn't support HTTP. I have never user X.509 certificate for that , can you please tell me how to authenticate against REST API using that, without OAuth access tokens?

Comment: also does it support refresh tokens?

Comment: This article may help you https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/configuring_authentication.html (there it explains how to configure authentication and user agent)

Comment: hey thanks a lot, the link you have send is for authenticating against OpenShift server. But I am specifically looking for OpenShift REST API authentication, any help on that?

Comment: This is specifically for REST API authentication https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/rest_api/index.html